# Why Is My Status Bar Not Changing Preferred Style?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, statusbar

I have `View controller-based status bar appearance` set to `YES` in my `Info.plist` file.

The view controller, not in a navigation stack, is presented via a modal segue. In it, I have the following property override for Swift 3/iOS 10:

```swift
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { return .lightContent }
```

Still, the status bar retains its default (dark) styling. However, when I print `preferredStatusBarStyle` in `viewDidLoad`, I get a `rawValue` of `1`. Checking out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistatusbarstyle/1623094-lightcontent), `1` refers to `.lightContent`.

I am trying to change the status bar's style to `.lightContent` because the view contains a `UIVisualEffectView` with a `UIBlurEffectStyle` value of `dark`.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 7):

With help from matt's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949166/why-is-my-status-bar-not-changing-preferred-style#answer-41949457), I was able to resolve my issue. I had to use the following in `viewDidLoad`:

```swift
modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
```

When I tried matt's solution, I received two compilation errors: `Cannot override mutable property with read-only property 'modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance'` and `Getter for 'modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance' with Objective-C selector 'modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance' conflicts with getter for 'modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance' from superclass 'UIViewController' with the same Objective-C selector`

Answer (score 5):

Add this to the modally presented view controller:

```
override var modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance: Bool { 
    return true
}
```

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue with a little tweaking of your solution. It seems that `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance ` is not a property that can be overridden since it's mutable. The compilation errors are provided in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

1. Go to info.plist and set **UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance** to **false**
2. Go to **AppDelegate.swift** then go to function **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**, set the color you want as below:

   **UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent**

Please let me know if it can help you.
Thanks.

Comment: I only need one view controller to have the light status bar, so setting it for the entire application is not ideal. However, I was able to find a solution, which is described in my answer.